# VB.NET Upload to FTP with progressbar

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp

I relise there is so many other questions out there regarding the progressbar, though I've looked through them "all" and can not find one that works.

I am trying to upload c:\screenshot.png to my ftp with a progress bar and a msgbox once finished.

Could someone provide a working example for me?

Thankyou

Edit heres the code I tried. Uploading works, though the progress bar dosent.

```
Sub UpdateProgressBar(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UploadProgressChangedEventArgs)
        If ProgressBar1.InvokeRequired Then
            ProgressBar1.Invoke(New UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(AddressOf UpdateProgressBar), sender, e)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ProgressBar1.Value = CInt(ProgressBar1.Minimum + _
        ((ProgressBar1.Maximum - ProgressBar1.Minimum) * _
          e.ProgressPercentage) / 100)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        Label16.Text = "Uploading now..."
        Label16.Update()


        Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()
        AddHandler client.UploadProgressChanged, AddressOf UpdateProgressBar

        With client
            .Credentials = New NetworkCredential( _
            "damon@slimar.eu", "mine123!")
            .UploadFile("ftp://slimar.eu/screenshot.png", "C:\screenshot.png")
        End With
        Label16.Text = "Done!"
        Label16.Update()

    End Sub
```

Comment: `though the progress bar dosent` Please explain this part. What happens? Does it freeze? Does the progress bar not visually update? How fast does the whole thing happen?

Answer (score 1):

Progress bar has minValue,Max value, StepValue which is used to perform a step and Value to setup arbitray value.When you uploading a file or downloading you should be able to see via e paramenter total byte and actual byte trasmission.So you can setup Progress bar value and max value.
Also personally i invite you to use backgroundworker which :

1. Not Freeze GUI
2. Give you much controll on thread with no issue and no invoke needs
3. Make it more simple :)